# Historical drivers behind demographics of Indigenous populations in American countries

Tags: native-americans, demography, colonial-america, spanish-empire

Today I run into [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_peoples_of_the_Americas#mediaviewer/File:Percentage_of_Amerindian_Population.png) (shown below) that shows what seems to be a stark difference in the percentage of indigenous populations in Spanish speaking countries vs other countries in the Americas (e.g. the US & Brazil).

Were there fundamental differences in the way Spanish vs non-Spanish speaking  countries were colonized that would specifically explain this difference?

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to "migrate" this map to the other question. Too bad it's a duplicate. This questionner actually made a good contribution!

Comment: @TomAu: If you appreciate this questioner's contribution, upvote the question.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Will the upvote be lost if the question is deleted as a duplicate.

Comment: @TomAu: I am not interested in deleting this question, even though I voted to close it as a duplicate. Are you?

Comment: There's no need to migrate the image. It's the exact same map as the duplicate question's (that's how I remembered in the first place).